# Instantiating object with foreignkey attribute with the Django shell

Tags: shell, django-models, foreign-keys

my question is quite simple :

In Django Shell how to instantiate an object which requires a foreign key attribute?

The models.py

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()
```

In the django shell...

```
p = Person(
        first_name="Fred"
       ,last_name="Flintstone"
       ,instrument="guitar"
    )

p.save()

...

a = Album(
        artist = " "               #<------ WHAT DO I PUT HERE ? :)))))
       ,name="u rock "
       ,release_date ="today"
       ,num_stars="4"
     )
a.save()
```

Thank you!

Amadeus

Answer (score 8):

When instantiating a model, ForeignKey fields need to be set to an instance of the appropriate related model. In your case:

```
p = Musician(
    first_name="Fred",
    last_name="Flintstone",
    instrument="guitar"
)
p.save()

import datetime
a = Album(
    artist=p,
    name="u rock",
    release_date=datetime.datetime.now().date(),
    num_stars=4
)
a.save()
```

Note that I've also fixed some of your typos, and used the correct data types for the release_date and num_stars attributes.